# Can't run macro via interop if it's in a worksheet?

Tags: c#, vba, excel, office-interop

I'm using the following code to run a VBA macro via C# Excel interop:

```
public void macroTest()
    {
        Excel.Application xlApp = new Excel.Application();
        xlApp.Visible = true;
        string bkPath = @"C:\somePath\someBk.xlsm";
        Excel.Workbook bk = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(bkPath);
        string bkName = bk.Name;
        string macroName = "testThisMacro_m";
        string runString = "'" + bkName + "'!"+macroName;
        xlApp.Run(runString);
        bk.Close(false);
        xlApp.Quit();
    }
```

`testThisMacro_m` is in a module `testMacro`, and this runs successfully.  When I replace it with:

```
string macroName = "testThisMacro_s";
```

where `testThisMacro_s` has its code in `Sheet1`, the `xlApp.Run()` line gives the following COM Exception:

```
Cannot run the macro ''someBk.xlsm'!testThisMacro_s'. 
The macro may not be available in this workbook or all macros may be disabled.
```

I checked macro security settings, and they are indeed set to "Disable with notification", but being able to run a macro from a module and not from a worksheet seems to indicate that this is a different issue than application-level macro security.

Is there something different that I have to do when making an interop call to a macro in a worksheet?

UPDATE: I was able to get the macro to execute by changing the call to:

```
string macroName = "Sheet1.testThisMacro_s"
```

but it seems that this hands control back to C# before the macro completes, so now I need to figure out how to check for macro completion (probably a different question).

Comment: Yes, different question in your update. Write up your finding as an "Answer", mark it to close the thread, and write a new question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get the macro to execute by changing the call to:

```
string macroName = "Sheet1.testThisMacro_s"
```

Answer (score 4):

A `Worksheet` object is an *object* - and objects are defined with *class modules*. Worksheets, workbooks, user forms; they're all objects. And you can't just call a method on an object, if you don't have an *instance* of that object.

Macros work off *standard modules*, which aren't objects, and don't need to be instantiated.

`Application.Run` can't call methods of an *object*, that's why macros need to be in standard modules.

Comment: I was able to get it to run by calling `Sheet1.testThisMacro_s`, but now I need to figure out how to detect when the macro has completed (see update to my OP).

Comment: @Mat'sMug Oh, but it seems you can, but only for document-type modules! Calling `Application.Run "Sheet1.Foo"` or `Application.Run "ThisWorkbook.Foo"` or (in Word) `Application.Run "ThisDocument.Foo"` all work. Unfortunately, It doesn't work with a predeclared class module, regardless of whether the class is PublicNotCreatable.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't a helper sub solve both of your problems, re: Mat's Mug's reply concerning instantiation?

In some standard module:

```
Sub testHelperSubToBeCalledFromInterop
    Call Sheet1.testThisMacro_s
End Sub
```

EDIT:

[image]

Comment: This is being run against many workbooks that all have the same template, so they would all need to have their code updated accordingly.  It would be preferable to find a solution that only involves modifying the C# code.

Comment: `Sheet1` used like this *is* an object instance: worksheets and userforms are class modules with their `VB_PredeclaredId` attribute set to `True`, which makes VBA create a global object instance named after the type (as mentioned [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35546689/cant-run-macro-via-interop-if-its-in-a-worksheet/35546854#comment58782513_35546854)).

Comment: @Mat'sMug: I thought the problem was limited to finding an entrypoint. You said `Application.Run` can't call methods of an object, which I do not contest, but I interpreted it as meaning that `Application.Run` *can* run methods in standard modules. So if you have a standard module with a macro that points to the sheet... doesn't that solve the problem? Putting a screenshot in my post. It seems to work "locally" in Excel, wouldn't it also work with interop?

Comment: @Mat'sMug Oh, in that case, my bad. I got the impression you were arguing counter to my solution. Glad we agree!